# (JavaScript) Enter keypress does not work in Mozila FireFox when dropdown control has ListSearchExtender

Tags: javascript

any one help me to solve my problem...

my page has munber of control... when page is loaded .one of conlrol is Focus().. when i Enter, the next control is Focus.. The Problem is DropDownlist has ListSearchExtender.. so when i enter, the next focus does not work in Mozila Firfox ... Its good working in IE..But not Mozi`la Firefox ..   Here my code Below...

```
function GotoNextFocus(ControlName, e) {   
          var unicode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
          var BrowserVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion);              
          if (unicode == 13) {
              var control = document.getElementById(ControlName);
              if (control != null) {
                  control.focus();
                  if (navigator.appName == "Mozilla"|| navigator.appName == "Netscape") {
                      e.preventDefault();                         
                  }                     
                  else {                    
                      if(BrowserVersion>=5) {
                         e.preventDefault();
                        }
                        else{
                        e.returnValue = false;
                        }                           
                  }              
              }
          }
      }
```